# How to show left-invariant frame?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working on the following problem and I'm stumped. What do I need to show? What does "left-invariant frame" mean?

> Consider $\mathbb{S}^3$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $(w, x, y, z)$. Show that there is a Lie group structure on $\mathbb{S}^3$ in which the vector fields $$ X_1 = -x\frac{\partial}{\partial w} + w\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - z\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + y\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ X_2 = -y\frac{\partial}{\partial w} +z\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +w\frac{\partial}{\partial y} -x\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ X_3 = -z\frac{\partial}{\partial w} -y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + w\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$form a left-invariant frame.

I can show that it is a frame by showing that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are linearly independent, but how do I show that they form a left-invariant frame?

Comment: Well, before you can show they form a left-invariant frame you need the Lie group structure. What group structure do you have in mind, or is that your actual question?

Comment: Above is the exact statement of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show whether they are left invariant frame or not, you have to impose them to Lie algebra then find structure constants.